# How to set a class_weight Dictionary for Random Forest?

Tags: classification, random-forest, class-imbalance

I'm dealing with an unbalanced dataset, so I decided to use a weight dictionary for classification.

Documentation says that a weight dict must be defined as shown below:
https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/generated/imblearn.ensemble.BalancedRandomForestClassifier.html

```
     weight_dict = [{0: 1, 1: 1}, {0: 1, 1: 5}, {0: 1, 1: 1}, {0: 1, 1: 1}]
```

So, since I want to predict 12 classes which are located in the last column.
I assume that the setting would be like:

```
weight_dict = [{0: 1, 1: 5.77390289e-01}, {0: 1, 1: 6.48317326e-01}, 
               {0: 1, 1: 1.35324885e-01}, {0: 1, 1: 2.92665797e+00}, 
               {0: 1, 1: 5.77858906e+01}, {0: 1, 1: 1.73193507e+00},
               {0: 1, 1: 9.27828244e+00}, {0: 1, 1: 1.18766082e+01}, 
               {0: 1, 1: 8.99009985e+01}, {0: 1, 1: 6.39833279e+00}, 
               {0: 1, 1: 2.55347077e+01}, {0: 1, 1: 9.47015372e+02}]
```

Honestly, I don't clearly understand the notation of the first indicators, I mean the:

```
      0:1 of {0: 1, 1: 1}
```

or the:

```
 1: value.
```

Do they represent column position, label order?

What is the right way to set it?

I'll be grateful for your insights.

Comment: can you provide a link on the documentation ?

Comment: Sure, https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/generated/imblearn.ensemble.BalancedRandomForestClassifier.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just doing multiclass classification, you should specify the weights as a single dictionary, e.g. `{0: 1.0, 1: 1.5, 2: 3.2}` for a three-class problem. (Or use the convenience modes `"balanced"` or `"balanced_subsample"`).

The list of dictionaries is used for multi**label** classification (where each row can have multiple true labels).  In that case, each dictionary is for one of the outputs, the keys being the classes for that output and values the weights.